# why the volume of $Q$ is equal to the volume of the closure of $Q$? Where $Q$ is an open cube.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given an open cube $Q\subset \mathbb R^n$, $\overline{Q}=Q\cup \alpha Q$ where $\overline{Q}$ is the closure of $Q$ and $\alpha Q$ is the boundary of $Q$. I know $|\overline{Q}|  =|Q|$，where $|Q|$ is the volume of $Q$. But how to prove it strictly. I have no idea to show $|\overline{Q}| \le |Q|$.

Comment: Hint: what is the volume of $\alpha Q$?

Comment: It is 0,and $|\overline{Q}|$=$|Q|$+$|\alpha{Q}|$=$|Q|$.It seems simple.Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Already answered by Jonathan Y. in a comment, but here is another approach, based on scaling. For every $\lambda>1$ the dilated cube $\lambda \cdot Q$ (same center, sidelength multiplied by $\lambda$) has volume $|\lambda\cdot Q|=\lambda^n |Q|$. Since $\overline{Q}\subset \lambda\cdot Q$, we have 
$$|\overline{Q}|\le \lambda^n |Q|$$
Since $\lambda>1$ was arbitrary, it follows that 
$$|\overline{Q}|\le  |Q|$$
The reverse inequality follows from the inclusion $Q\subset \overline{Q}$.